# Rules of the mining pools for mining software and weight blockchain Litecoin

Tags: blockchain, mining-pools, litecoin

1. What rules must a mining software fulfill in order for a pool to allow mining with the ?, example of a pool please.
2. How heavy is Liteco's chain of blocks at this moment or where can I consult it?

Comment: There are no real rules, besides requiring that any blocks broadcasted by a pool validate against consensus requirements. How the pool distributes the work and constructs blocks is entirely up to them.